# Google analytics - Display active users of current session

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I want to display Google Analytics - active users of current session data in Chart.

This is my code.

```
 var timeline = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
                    reportType: 'ga',
                    query: {
                        'dimensions': 'ga:date',
                        'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
                        'start-date': '2daysAgo',
                        'end-date': 'today',
                    },
                    chart: {
                        type: 'LINE',
                        container: 'timeline'
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Usually there's a question.